# Запуск php скриптов

Tags: php

Каким образом запускаются php скрипты (опишите подробно, пожалуйста).

Comment: Вам под какую операционку?

Comment: Windows.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, очень подробно действие за действием. Я ничего не знаю.

Comment: Как писали уже в ответах, denwer идеальный вариант. Это готовый веб-сервер под виндами. Там же в доках описано, как и куда создавать скрипты, чтобы они запускались и как их запускать.

Comment: я установил denwer/каким образом его запускать?

Comment: При установке, на рабочем столе должны появиться 3 иконки Start Denwer, Restart Denwer, Stop Denwer. Start Denwer - запускает веб-сервер. Читай документации к денверу, там все подробно описано.

Comment: выдает ошибку: Apache monitor is already started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую VertrigoServ устанавливаете, запускаете иконку на рабочем столе, в трее появится иконка вертриго, щелкаете на нее правой кнопкой мыши выбираем пункт "WWW folder" откроется папка, удаляем из нее все содержимое, и копируем сюда файлы нужного вам скрипта, далее идем в браузер и переходим на http://127.0.0.1/ и смотрим на скрипт!

Answer (score 0):

1. Качается и устанавливается веб сервер(apache+php).
2. Запускается веб сервер(apache).
3. На веб сервер закидываются php скрипты.
4. ?????
5. PROFIT

Answer (score 0):

Для изучения достаточно установить готовый пакет. [denwer.ru](http://denwer.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Ставите XAMPP на диск C. Запускаете сервер (на рабочем столе ярлычок после установки появится). Открываете на диске С папочку сервера, в ней есть папка htdoc. Кладете туда скрипт. Потом открываете браузер, пишете в нем localhost/имяскрипта.php и смотрите результат.

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнения (запуска) пхп-скриптов, нужен ПХП интерпритатор, который преобразовывает ваш код в машинный и выполняет.

Для трансляции результатов вашего кода в браузере нужна "машина", которая будет запросы направлять к пхп интерпретатору и результат передаст вашему браузеру. Таковыми являются IIS, APACHE, NGNIX и т.д.. Все вместе называют веб-сервером.

Соответственно, чтобы "запустить" ваш скрипт под виндой нужен веб-сервер Apache+PHP[+MySQL].  Затем смело можете писать скрипты и пропускать их через пхп интерпретатор и apache.